# Node.js Socket.io sets up multiple connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

Im creating a simple socket.io chat that uses passport.js for authentication. But everytime a user logout and login the old socket connection reconnects. This causes a problem because now there are two active connections to one page. So what I want to do is end the current connection when the user navigates to "/logout".

```
var socketNotLoaded = true;
var socket;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if(socketNotLoaded) { //is true when new connection is required
            require("./socket")(io,req.user) //runs the socket.io script
            socketNotLoaded = false;
        }
        res.render('index', pug.get(req.user));
    } else {
        res.render('notloggedin', pug.get());
    }
})

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
    socketNotLoaded = true;
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/');
})
```

Im using

- socket.io: 2.0.3
- passport: 0.4.0
- passport-local: 1.0.0
- express: 4.15.4
- express-session: 1.15.5
- cookie-parser: 1.4.3
- body-parser: 1.17.2

Comment: Apparently you have client code in your web pages that is reconnecting after you logout and reconnect.  That's likely where the problem is.  Plus, your code appears to be designed only for one user.  If `if(socketNoLoaded)` call is using a module level variable to decide whether to initialize socket.io with `req.user`.  That just doesn't make sense.  What do you expect to happen when the second user comes to your site? Or the third user?

Comment: Oh I see. How should I fix that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Your current design looks to me to be fundamentally flawed.  Per-user state needs to be in your session, not in module level variables.  The socket.io server should be initialized when the server starts up and at the same time your web server is initialized.  It should always be running and it should not be initialized with any per-user state.  You don't make a new socket.io server for each user, you have ONE socket.io server that all users use (just like your web server).

Comment: Thank you, now it makes more sense. But how would I then securely give socket.io the active users details?

Comment: I don't know what "give it the active users details" means?  What are "active users details" and why are you wanting to give them to the socket.io server?

Comment: The information that was previously passed from req.user.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that information?  What is it?  Shouldn't it just  be in your session object?  Your question says you're using express-session.

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side when the user wants to logout, you could perform a `socket.emit('exit');`, then on the server-side have a listener like so:

```
socket.on('exit', function(){
    socket.disconnect();
});
```

And that will disconnect the client from Socket.io. You could also create an object on the server-side that maps a username to a Socket.io socket ID, and perform a check to see if that user already exists. If it does, then you can disconnect that socket ID on the server-side. Ideally, the client should send a `disconnect` to the server when the user logs out. Something like this:

```
 $('#logout').click( function() {
            socket.disconnect();
            window.location = "/logout";
});
```

Comment: I've tried that, but there are still two live connections the second time you login.

Comment: The client can just  disconnect anytime it wants to.  It doesn't need to send the server a message to tell the server to disconnect.  Plus, the OP's code is redirecting after logout so the current socket connection will be killed upon redirect anyway.

Comment: As @jfriend00 said, you can have the client disconnect. We don't know how you are doing this because you have not provided your client-side code.

Comment: All that happens on the client side is that the user is redirected to "/logout" and an initial connect.
var socket = io.connect(window.location.href.split("/")[2]);

Comment: Well, assuming that logging out is something like a button click, make an event listener for that button, then call `socket.disconnect()`, then do the redirect `window.location = "/logout";`

Comment: @RetroGamer - There's no need to disconnect a socket in a page that is about to redirect.  The browser will do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. But as a failsafe, if for instance they were using angular and had multiple socket connections in different controllers for example, then this might be needed because if you are using routes, technically there may not be a page reload/refresh or whatever. But you do have a point :)

Comment: @RetroGamer - That could be true in a single page web app where you never reload the page, but this question is explicitly about a redirect where the whole page is going to be replaced and the browser will shut-down all resources associated with that page for you.

Comment: @jfriend00 Understood. Thanks.